# Cordova can 2 plugin interact with each other?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, plugins

I'm trying to make a cordova app (IOS and android), I found a plugins that would do 80% of what I want to do and I was wondering, is it possible to make my own plugins and use the class defined in the other plugin ? At first sight, I would say yes, but I don't really know how cordova work with multiple plugin...

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova allows multiple use of plugins and since most of them are opensource you can modify as you want. You can think of them as java packages to be simpler. So, of course you can reference the classes from different packages to each other(I'm talking about Android side).